# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget-package, assembly-resolution

After installing Microsoft.Aspnet.Webapi.Webhost package to my web api project, I end up with the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling the NuGet package, which corrects broken dependencies. From the package manager, run Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall.

Comment: I got this problem just on IIS. Under developing environment it works Ok.

Comment: This command to reinstall package did help me. ASP.NET Web API 2 (v5.2.0), Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 3):

When I installed using System.Web.Http.Cors from nugget I get above error.Then I updated webApi Package to latest version.Fixed Issue.